# Parent and Child Coroutines not getting cancelled

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Parent Coroutine with a Child Coroutine like this:

```
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler {_,e -> println("exception $e")}

        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

        mainCoroutineJob = scope.launch(exceptionHandler){

            val data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                val data = getData()
                data
            }
            data?.let{
                // do something with data
            }
        }
```

When I try to cancel both the parent and child coroutines using this:

```
mainCoroutineJob.cancel("Coroutine Cancelled")
mainCoroutineJob.cancelChildren(CancellationException("Coroutine Cancelled"))
```

the code inside withContext, keeps on running.

May I know why? And how can we cancel the withContext as well?

Comment: How do you check the cancellation of the coroutine? Note that when the coroutine is cancelled, exceptionHandler will not be called.

Comment: I don’t see a child coroutine.

Comment: @IR42 the code inside withContext keeps running even after using .cancel(), thats my issue

Comment: `withContext` is not considered a child coroutine. How do you determine it’s still running? There are only two lines of code. By the time it has been cancelled, the first line of code has likely already been called. The second line of code doesn't do anything because it's just a return value. There's nothing to cancel. If `getData()` is a suspend function, then it will be canceled when it reaches its next suspension point (calling a suspend function internally) or if it manually checks `isActive` and returns early if it's false. If it doesn't have either of those, it has nothing to cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withContext` is a `suspend` function, not a `coroutine builder`, therefore there's no child coroutine. The reason why it's not stopping when the job is cancelled is because it is not cooperative. You need to make your `getData` cooperatively cancellable. I assume it is already a `suspend` function, if so, then you just need to check at critical points whether the job that is running that `suspend` function still active and proceed only if it is. You can check it by using `coroutineContext.isActive` inside of a `suspend` function.

A critical point might be a loop or if there's no loop but a function is still doing some heavy processing you can divide your function into chunks and then before proceeding into processing the next chunk you check whether the `suspend` function's job is still active or not, and proceed only if it is active.